# negative Flexi time logging using a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still a Noob when it comes to VBA, but I'm gradually picking it up as I go along. I need help trying to get my simple Flexitime input form to log flexi time "taken" as negative time (-01:00) on a spreadsheet, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Private Sub submit_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim irow As Long

    Set wb = FlexBook
    Set ws = FlexBook.Worksheets("Flex Data")

    irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row





    If Trim(Me.employee.Value) = "" Then
        Me.employee.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please select a name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "" Then
        Me.owta.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please select whether it is time taken or time owed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.Time.Value) = "" Then
        Me.Time.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please input the amount of time"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.dateflex.Value) = "" Then
        Me.dateflex.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please input the date the flex was owed or taken"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.author.Value) = "" Then
        Me.author.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please confirm who has authorised this"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    If Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "Owed" Then
        Time = Time

    ElseIf Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "Taken" Then
        Time = Time * -1

        Exit Sub
    End If



'Insert data in to the table

ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value = Me.employee.Value
ws.Cells(irow, 2).Value = Me.owta.Value
'ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = ? <---cell to indicate positive or negative time
ws.Cells(irow, 4).Value = CDate(Me.dateflex.Value)
ws.Cells(irow, 5).Value = Me.author.Value


'clear the data
Me.employee.Value = ""
Me.owta.Value = ""
Me.Time.Value = ""
Me.dateflex.Value = ""
Me.author.Value = ""
Me.employee.SetFocus



End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at changing your spreadsheet to the 1904 date system - this allows minus dates/times  to be shown

Answer (score 1):

You could use an instant If, an If block, or a Select Case - your choice:

```
ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = IIf(Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "Owed", "+", "-")
'// However I wouldn't advise this if you want to evaluate "Owed" and "Taken" seperately.
```

or

```
If Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "Owed" Then
    ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = "+"
ElseIf Trim(Me.owta.Value) = "Taken" Then
    ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = "-"
End If
```

or

```
Select Case Trim(Me.owta.Value)
    Case "Owed": ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = "+"
    Case "Taken": ws.Cells(irow, 3).Value = "-"
End Select
```

All have their own pros and cons, but in the context in which you are using them will show little difference.